# Basic singlepage blog application

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I've started learning [Mithril framework](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/), which looks pretty awesome. I've created a basic blog app and have a few questions about code style and structure.

```
var app = {};

app.PostList = function(list) {
  return m.prop(list || []);
};

app.vm = {};

app.Post = function(data) {
  var data = data || {};
  this.id = m.prop(data.id);
  this.title = m.prop(data.title);
  this.content = m.prop(data.content);
};

app.vm.init = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.posts = new app.PostList();
  m.request({method: 'GET', url: '/posts', background: true, type: app.Post})
    .then(self.posts)
    .then(m.redraw);
};

app.controller = function() {
  app.vm.init();
};

app.view = function(ctrl) {
  return m('body', [
      m('h1', 'My blog'),
      m('ul',
        app.vm.posts().map(function(el){
          return m('li', [
            m('a[href="/posts/'+el.id()+'"]', {config: m.route}, JSON.stringify(el))
          ]);
        })
      ),
      m('a[href="/posts/add/"]', {config: m.route}, 'add new post')
  ]);
};

var add = {};

add.newPost = function(data) {
  data = data || {};
  this.title = data.title || '';
  this.content = data.content || '';
};

add.controller = function() {
  var post = new add.newPost();
  this.post = post;
  this.create = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    m.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/posts',
      data: post
    }).then(function() {m.route('/');});
  };
};

// data binding helper function
// http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/asymmetrical-data-bindings.html
function formBinds(data) {
  return function(e) {data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;};
}

add.view = function(ctrl) {
  return m('body', [
    m('form', {
      onsubmit: ctrl.create,
      onchange: formBinds(ctrl.post)
    }, [
      m('a[href="/"]', {config: m.route}, 'All Posts'),
      m('br'),
      m('input[type=text][name=title][placeholder="post title"][required]'),
      m('br'),
      m('textarea[name=content][placeholder="post content"][required]'),
      m('br'),
      m('input[type=submit][value=Post]')
    ])
  ]);
};

var details = {};

details.vm = {};
details.vm.init = function(postId) {
  var self = this;
  self.comment = {
    postId: postId,
    name: '',
    body: ''
  };
  self.post = new app.Post();
  m.request({method: 'GET', url: '/posts/'+postId, type: app.Post}).then(function(data) {
    data = data[0];
    self.post = data;
  });
  self.comments = m.request({method: 'GET', url: '/posts/'+postId+'/comments'});

  self.add = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (self.comment.body) {
      var newComment = self.comment;
      // TODO: add request error handler (how to?)
      m.request({method: 'POST', url: '/posts/'+postId+'/comments', data: newComment}).then(function() {
        var comments = self.comments();
        comments.push(newComment);
        self.comments(comments);
      });
    }
  }.bind(self);
};

details.controller = function() {
  var postId = +m.route.param('postId');
  this.postId = postId;
  details.vm.init(postId);
};

details.view = function(ctrl) {
  return m('body', [
    m('a[href="/"]', {config: m.route}, 'All posts'),
    m('h1', details.vm.post.title()),
    m('p', details.vm.post.content()),
    m('form', {
      onsubmit: details.vm.add,
      onchange: formBinds(details.vm.comment)
    }, [
      m('input[type=text][name=name][placeholder="your name"][required]'),
      m('br'),
      m('textarea[name=body][placeholder="comment body"][required]'),
      m('br'),
      m('input[type=submit][value=Post]')
    ]),
    m('ul', details.vm.comments().map(function(comment) {
      return m('li', comment.name+': '+comment.body);
    }))
  ]);
};

//setup routes to start w/ the `#` symbol
m.route.mode = 'hash';

//define a route
m.route(document, '/', {
    '/' : app,
    '/posts/add': add,
    '/posts/:postId': details
});
```

You can find the complete project on [my GitHub](https://github.com/Edifear/mithril-samples).
Please, provide some advice or comments about how to implement it with Mithril.

Comment: You might get more from this if you ask your style and structure questions instead of just mentioning that they exist.  Some people who might not answer otherwise may respond to specific questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed you're using `app` as a module name (which is understandable, since it's what the tutorial in the Mithril site does now). For real apps, you should try to name your modules more descriptively. For example, if the module displays a list of Posts, you might want to call it `posts` or `postList`.

---

Instead of calling `m.request` from `vm`, I normally pull the request out into a method on the model class, for example:

```
var Post = function(data) {
  var data = data || {};
  this.id = m.prop(data.id);
  this.title = m.prop(data.title);
  this.content = m.prop(data.content);
}
Post.list = function() {
  return m.request({method: 'GET', url: '/posts', type: app.Post})
}
```

You might optionally want to wrap `m.request` itself in another method, e.g.

```
var req = function(args) {
  return m.request(args)
}
/*...*/
Post.list = function() {
  return req({method: 'GET', url: '/posts', type: app.Post})
}
```

This lets you easily configure requests globally (e.g. if you need to set HTTP headers on all requests)

On a side note, I generally don't recommend using the `background:true` + `m.redraw` combo (especially on first render), unless you have a really good reason. When you do that, you're allowing your view to run early, which means all of your asynchronous data needs to be considered nullable, which in turn means you need more defensive code in the view. It's also a band-aid solution if the root of the problem is a slow web service.

---

Re: this comment: "TODO: add request error handler (how to?)"

Assuming you created a model method for posting as well:

```
Post.save = function(args) {
  return m.request({method: 'POST', url: '/posts', data: args, unwrapError: unwrap})
}
```

Then you can use the rejection handler of the promise to bind errors to a getter-setter

```
self.error = m.prop("")
self.add = function() {
  /*...*/
  Post.save()
    .then(null, self.error)
}
```

You can define the `unwrapError` function to drill down into a response to get the desired error message string out of the JSON structure. (There's also the `extract` option which lets you handle the response at the XHR level)

So, if your response looks like `{msg: "something died"}`, then you could write `unwrapError: function(e) {return e.msg}`, and then to display the error, you would simply call `vm.error()` in the view, which would return the `"something died"` string.

---

I also normally use a layout wrapping module, which looks something like this:

```
var layout = {}

layout.controller = function(module) {
  this.controller = new module.controller
  this.view = module.view
}

layout.view = function(ctrl) {
  return m(".layout", [
    ctrl.view(ctrl.controller)
  ])
}

layout.wrap = function(routes) {
  var map = {}
  Object.keys(routes).map(function(r) {
    map[r] = {
      controller: function() {
        return new layout.controller(routes[r])
      },
      view: layout.view
    }
  })
  return map
}
```

Then I can wrap modules like this:

```
m.route(document, "/", layout.wrap({
  "/": posts
}))
```

With this, the inner modules don't need to redefine the layout stuff all the time.

Regarding usage of `vm` versus using the controller, you only really need view-models if you need your modules to be globally accessible by other modules (this usually only happens when you have a deep hierarchy of sub-templates).

Most of the time, using fat controllers yield shorter, clearer code than using view-models (see app.vm.init + app.controller vs add.controller).

Still on the topic of controllers, one technique that I've seen in angular styleguides is to code controllers like this:

```
foo.controller = function() {
  var foo = {bar: 1}
  return {
    foo: foo
    doStuff: doStuff
  }

  function doStuff() {
    alert(foo.bar)
  }
}
```

This style avoids issues with `this` scoping and makes it easier to scan the public signature of the controller.

---

When using `m.route`, I recommend that you bind to `document.body` instead of `document`, so that you can put stylesheets in `<head>` and take advantage of the browser downloading/rendering optimizations.

---

Other than those, the code looks fairly well organized. The views are well written, and the code is easy to read, overall.

Comment: I tried to refactor project as described in you question but discover some problems. Please, look to this [sample](http://pastebin.com/6FGzCQHr).

Comment: And, please provide a real sample of refactored controller. I tried to do that but miss some point

Comment: Oops, sorry I was typing from memory and mistyped. In layout.view, it should have been ctrl.view(ctrl.controller), not ctrl.view(ctrl.module). On your pastebin, this also means you need to change module.controller.posts() to just ctrl.posts() (assuming the argument to the view function is called ctrl instead of module)

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/wHETJ61Y for a refactored version of app.controller

Comment: Thanks Leo! Your framework looks great but lacks examples. I found a good [article of yours](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/prototypes-closures-and-the-zen-of-javascript-oop.html) which describes issue with controller

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on getting better examples up on the site. Thanks for the feedback